How to access a parent attribute in XML
I can't seem to correct the LINQ syntax - or I don't know how to reference XML objects.
I have XML like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Targets>
    <FileType TargetId="image">
        <FileExtension>jpg</FileExtension>
        <FileExtension>jpeg</FileExtension>
        <FileExtension>tif</FileExtension>
        <FileExtension>tiff</FileExtension>
        <FileExtension>gif</FileExtension>
        <FileExtension>png</FileExtension>
    </FileType>
</Targets>

I want to look up/extract the "TargetId" where the file extension matches the one I am looking for, say "jpeg".
Firstly, this is the first time I have used a structure with a list of the same element names "FileExtension".
And it never seems to find it.
I am basing this on previous test code with XML like:
<body>
  <Customers>
    <Client TestAttr="testing-123">
        <Firstname>someguy</Firstname>
        <LastName>some other last name again</LastName>
        <PhoneNumber>12345634543</PhoneNumber>
        <City>some other town</City>
        <State>some other state</State>
    </Client>
  </Customers>
</body>

The code:
IEnumerable<XElement> someClients =
   from el in doc.Elements("Customers").Elements("Client")
   where (string)el.Element("PhoneNumber") == phoneNumberToFind
   select el;

does find the one I am looking for. then I can get another element within the same "Client" with:
Console.WriteLine("Found client named '{0}'", (string)el.Element("LastName").Value );

and printing el gives the following - everything is in one chunk:-
<Client TestAttr="testing-123">
  <Firstname>someguy</Firstname>
  <LastName>some other last name again</LastName>
  <PhoneNumber>12345634543</PhoneNumber>
  <City>some other town</City>
  <State>some other state</State>
</Client>

Secondly, all my attempts to access the attribute at the parent level are met with

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ......dll: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Attempts tried include:
string fTestAttr1 = (string)el.Element("Client").Value;
string fTestAttr2 = (string)el.Element("Client").Attribute("TestAttr");
string fTestAttr3 = (string)el.Element("Client").Attribute("TestAttr").Value; 
string fTestAttr4 = (string)el.Element("Client").FirstAttribute.Value;   
string fTestAttr4 = (string)el.Element("Client").FirstAttribute.Value);

So clearly I don't know how to address the parent. Not helped by VS Code debug where I can see el is XElement but it does not have any Element.
Thanks for any support
JC

All you need to do is to change "select el" which is returning the entire element in one chunk to following : select new { firstname = (string)el.Element("Firstname"), lastname = (string)el.Element("LastName")};  With Linq using Value will give an error when you have a null.  Using casting like I did will avoid the null error.

With the query, it returns IEnumerable of Client/FileType XElement. Hence you don't need the extra .Element("Client")/.Element("FileType") as it will treat as there is a descendant with Client/<FileType>.
Obtain the attribute value: result.Attribute("TargetId").Value.
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
            <Targets>
                <FileType TargetId=""image"">
                    <FileExtension>jpg</FileExtension>
                    <FileExtension>jpeg</FileExtension>
                    <FileExtension>tif</FileExtension>
                    <FileExtension>tiff</FileExtension>
                    <FileExtension>gif</FileExtension>
                    <FileExtension>png</FileExtension>
                </FileType>
                <FileType TargetId=""doc"">
                    <FileExtension>doc</FileExtension>
                </FileType>
            </Targets>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement root = doc.Root;

XElement result = (from el in doc.Elements("Targets").Elements("FileType")
    where el.Elements("FileExtension").Any(x => (string)x == "jpg")
    select el).FirstOrDefault();

            
Console.WriteLine(result.Attribute("TargetId").Value);

Alternatively, working with XPath:
string targetId = root.XPathSelectElement("/Targets/FileType[FileExtension='jpg']").Attribute("TargetId").Value;

The same goes for Client: Obtain the attribute value: result2.Attribute("TestAttr").Value.
string xml2 = @"<body>
          <Customers>
            <Client TestAttr=""testing-123"">
                <Firstname>someguy</Firstname>
                <LastName>some other last name again</LastName>
                <PhoneNumber>12345634543</PhoneNumber>
                <City>some other town</City>
                <State>some other state</State>
            </Client>
          </Customers>
        </body>";
        
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(xml2);
XElement root2 = doc2.Root;
        
XElement result2 = (from el in doc2.Element("body").Elements("Customers").Elements("Client")
    where el.Elements("PhoneNumber").Any(x => (string)x == "12345634543")
    select el).FirstOrDefault();
        
Console.WriteLine(result2.Attribute("TestAttr").Value);

Alternatively, working with XPath:
string testAttr = root2.XPathSelectElement("/body/Customers/Client[PhoneNumber=12345634543]").Attribute("TestAttr").Value;


Demo @ .NET Fiddle

Youg - thank you for this. Retrieving the Attribute worked. It seems my mistake was includeing too much in this case '.Element("Client")'  However for the 'find'  - with the list of 'FileExtension' this only works for the first in the list ie, from above, it will find 'jpg' or 'doc' but not 'tiff'.  Could that be something to do with FirstOrDefault??   It is a fundamental difference between my attempt (which returned a set) and yours which aims at one result - which is obviously better if I can understand it more. Thanks again

Hi, because Element will get the first element. If you want to find any element, you should work with Elements() and Any(). Please check my latest answer. Thanks.

Yong, Thanks again. Your suggestions do work (of course) but I think the XPath solutions you offer are far easier to understand to a novice such as myself.
